# Docker for Mac vs Docker for Windows

Tags: windows, docker, macos, containers, virtual-machine

I'm very new to Docker. My current understanding is that the concept of docker containers is different than virtualization in the sense that the docker engine runs as a user application on top of the host operating system ONLY, creating a container which is essentially another computer/endpoint, which is isolated from your host computer. After exploring the internet for a bit, I read in multiple places that this is indeed how it works when it comes to Windows, but not the case when it comes to MacOS, in which the docker containers are said to be run on top of a Linux VM. Is this correct? If so, does this not miss the whole point of docker being able to run applications in an isolated environment WITHOUT the need for a VM that is running on top of your host OS and requiring many resources? I kindly ask for someone to explain to me the whole picture here.

Thanks a lot!

Tried to understand how Docker works on mac, expected the same behaviour as Windows but found out something else.

Comment: You intrinsically need a Linux kernel to be able to run Linux binaries, and running multiple kernels usually requires a virtual machine.  If you were on a native-Linux host, and you weren't using Docker Desktop, then you'd get the behavior you describe.  (I don't actually know how Windows Subsystem for Linux works.)